# Spring LDAP not working with LDAP template

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I am trying to connect to LDAP server using spring
The available information about LDAP server is the following:

1. host/ip
2. port
3. domain => ou=x,dc=y,dc=z
   I don't have any info about the filtration method such as uid = {0} or cn = {0} which matches the username

Here is my code

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.DefaultDirObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;

@Configuration
public class LdapConfiguration {
    
  @Bean
  public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
      LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
      contextSource.setUrl("ldap://ip:port");
      contextSource.setBase("dc=y,dc=z");
      return contextSource;
  }
    
    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        LdapTemplate template = new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
    
        return template;
    }
}
```

Then in another class here is the authentication method

```
@Service
public class LdapUserServiceImpl implements LdapUserService, BaseLdapNameAware {

  @Autowired
  protected LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;
  
  @Autowired
  protected ContextSource contextSource;

  @Override
  public Boolean authenticate(String userDn, String credentials) {

      AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
      filter.and(new EqualsFilter("uid", userDn));
      boolean authenticated = ldapTemplate.authenticate(LdapUtils.emptyLdapName(), filter.toString(), credentials);
      
      return authenticated;
   }
}
```

I have got the following error:

> m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized
> exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is
> javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr:
> DSID-0C090A7D, comment: In order to perform this operation a
> successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v3839

My question is what is the reason for this error, also what can I do if no pattern is known as uid={0} or it is standard
Also, I tried to put in the ContextSource initialization username and password, although they are assumed not to be available by me

```
  contextSource.setUserDn("uid=username,ou=x,dc=y,dc=z"); 
  contextSource.setPassword("password");
```

This gives me the following error:

> [nio-8005-exec-5] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code
> 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090453, comment: AcceptSecurityContext
> error, data 52e, v3839

In the application.properties file, I put

```
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=y,dc=z
spring.ldap.embedded.port=port
```

Answer (score 0):

Set userDn as username@domainname.com.
`contextSource.setUserDn("uid=username,ou=x,dc=y,dc=z");`
Here to me, ou=x, looks to be extra, below statement should make it work.
`contextSource.setUserDn("uid=username,dc=y,dc=z");`

Regards
Abhi

Comment: Thanks alot, but my problem is that I don't have an initial username to set the UserDn with in the configuration class